# Controlar entrada de datos en un input por JS

Tags: javascript, input

Tengo una función en JS para controlar lo que el usuario puede o no introducir por teclado.
Ahora mismo llamo a esa función mediante un `onkeypress` de manera que cada vez que el usuario teclea en el input compruebo que es correcto.

Ahora tengo el problema de que si copia y pega un texto en ese input al no haber tecleado una tecla no se llama a la función, he probado con el `onchange` pero con el problema de que si copio y pego en ese input y directamente doy al botón submit no llama a la función.

¿Cual es la forma correcta para poder llamar a esa función en cualquier caso posible?

Comment: Has probado con [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur)?

Comment: Puedes usar el evento [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar los eventos del clipboard, aqui te dejo copiar, cortar y pegar.

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").oncopy = function(e){        
 document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = e.type;
}
 
   
document.querySelector("textarea").oncut = function(e){    
 document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = e.type;
}
 
   
document.querySelector("textarea").onpaste = function(e){
 document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = e.type;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<p></p>
```